# Error 2664 - Can't convert from std::vector<...> to std::tr1::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Need help with an error message that I just can't figure out. I am getting the following:

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(_Ty &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Physics::Box2D' to 'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty> &&'    d:\visual studio 2010\projects\c++\test001\main.cpp 31  1   Test001
```

Not sure why, the code should work. I found sample code on StackOverFlow.com Maybe I am missing something.

Please help...newbie boost library user

```
//this code works fine...
Box2D *b = new Box2D();
b->Info();

//but this code fails...
vector< shared_ptr<Box2D> > boxes;
boxes.push_back( new Box2D() );  <--error happens here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor for `std::shared_ptr<T>` taking a pointer to `T` is `explicit`, i.e. you can't implicitly convert to this type. Also, the error message doesn't seem to match the code. However, try this:

```
boxes.push_back(std::shared_ptr<Box2D>(new Box2D()));
```

... or

```
boxes.push_back(std::make_shared<Box2D>());
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Figured out what I was missing by looking a bit harder at the sample code I was earlier viewing